# Vim not storing numbered registers

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

I've read that Vim automatically stores previously yanked texts into registers from 1 to 9, being 1 the previous yank, 2 the second previous, and so on...

But this is not working for me.
Here is a screencast showing that registers 1-9 are not being populated: https://streamable.com/rmyxhl

How can I configure vim to keep previous yanked texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a code to do this.
Registers 1-9 would be used.

Register 0 gets override with the current yank, so you need to save the last yank.

```
function! SaveLastReg()
    if v:event['regname']==""
        if v:event['operator']=='y'
            for i in range(8,1,-1)
                exe "let @".string(i+1)." = @". string(i) 
            endfor
            if exists("g:last_yank")
                let @1=g:last_yank
            endif
            let g:last_yank=@"
        endif 
    endif
endfunction 

:autocmd TextYankPost * call SaveLastReg()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was already thinking of writing a function for this just didn't had the time yet. It is better than install a plugin with features I don't use, IMO. :)

Comment: yep, I actually hoped for a few days that someone else would write. And the plugins seemed cumbersome.

Answer (score 7):

> Vim automatically stores previously yanked texts into registers from 1 to 9

That's not accurate. Registers 1 through 9 are actually used for the previously *delete* or *change* commands.

Yank commands store their results in register 0, unless a named register is explicitly specified.

See [`:help "1`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote1) (emphasis mine):

> Vim fills these registers with text from yank and delete commands.
>
> Numbered register 0 contains the text from the most recent yank command,
> unless the command specified another register with `"x`.
>
> **Numbered register 1 contains the text deleted by the most recent delete or change command**, unless the command specified another register or the text is less than one line (the small delete register is used then). [...]

(And then it goes on to explain exceptions when a delete is less than one line, but it uses `"1` instead of `"-` anyways...)

> How can I configure vim to keep previous yanked texts?

There's no native configuration for this feature, so you'd have to use a plug-in.

A quick search led me to find [vim-yoink](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-yoink) and [YankRing.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim), among a few others, which implement such a feature (not necessarily using the same yank command or the existing numbered registers.) You might want to consider taking a look at some of these if you're interested in such a feature.